# XGBOOST objective function derivation algebra

Tags: regression, machine-learning, boosting

I need some help please with the derivation of xgboost objective function. I am following this online tutorial ([Math behind GBM and XGBoost](https://medium.com/@vikeshsingh37/math-behind-gbm-and-xgboost-d00e8536b7de))

How do you go from here 
$$
loss =  \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \left( g_i \sum_{j=1}^{T} b_{jm}I_{Rjm}(x_i) + \frac{1}{2} k_i \left( \sum_{j=1}^{T} b_{jm}I_{Rjm}(x_i)  \right)^2 \right) +  \gamma T +  \frac{ \lambda }{2} \sum_{j=1}^{T} b_{jm}^2
$$

to here
$$
loss = \sum_{j=1}^{T} \left( \sum_{i\in I_{jm}} g_i \right) b_{jm} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{i\in I_{jm}} (k_i + \lambda) \right) b_{jm} + \gamma T 
$$

where as I understand, $I_j$ is the set of all training instances that are mapped to leaf $j$

I tried swapping the sums; however, since the second sum is squared I was not sure if they can be swapped.

Example, this is true

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} x_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{ij}
$$

but not sure if this can be swapped

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{m} x_{ij} \right)^2 
$$

Also, it may be the case that I don't fully understand the $I_{jm}$ function and how it works.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The quick answers to your question are:

1. You are absolutely right: it is not generally valid to swap the order of summation when the interior sum is squared. It's not even true when $n=1$ and $m=2$:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{1} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{2} x_{ij} \right)^2 = (x_{11} + x_{12})^2 = x_{11}^2 + 2x_{11}x_{12} + x_{12}^2
$$

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{1} x_{ij} \right)^2 = x_{11}^2 + x_{12}^2
$$

2. The [blog post](https://medium.com/@vikeshsingh37/math-behind-gbm-and-xgboost-d00e8536b7de) has a few mistakes in it, and you would be better working through the (quite nicely written and much better type-scripted) introduction in the [XGBoost docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html).